# Abrir em determinada foto, slick carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

É possível que ao abrir o `slick carousel`, determinada foto esteja em foco? algum tipo de mapeamento de indices ou até mesmo pelo nome, caso não, existe algum outro slide `drag and drop` que faz isso? exemplo...

```
  <div class="your-class">
    <img src="img1">
    <img src="img2"> <!-- abrir aqui -->
    <img src="img3">
  </div>

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a propriedade **initialSlide** para configurar qual o slide inicial.

Observe também a documentação da biblioteca: [Documentação](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)

Comment: Consultei a documentação, mas esse método me passou despercebido, obrigado!